# Joining results from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE person AS (
    id    INTEGER,
    sa    VARCHAR2
)

CREATE TABLE sampletest AS (
    sa    VARCHAR2, 
    cell  VARCHAR2,
    pd    VARCHAR2
)
```

I would like to get this output

```
SA | CELL | PD
```

this works:

```
SELECT person.*, 
       sampletest.* 
FROM       person 
INNER JOIN sampletest 
        ON person.sa = sampletest.sa;
```

but I want to condition this like:

```
SELECT person.*, 
       sampletest.* 
FROM  person 
WHERE person.sa = "S123" 
INNER JOIN sampletest 
        ON person.sa = sampletest.sa;
```

but this does not work...

Comment: There is no VARCHAR2 datatype in MySQL. Check your DBMS name carefully/

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should go after the join: `SELECT person.*, sampletest.* from person inner join sampletest on person.sa = sampletest.sa WHERE person.sa = "S123";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pospone the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT 
    person.*, 
    sampletest.* 
FROM 
    person 
INNER JOIN 
    sampletest 
ON 
    person.sa = sampletest.sa 
WHERE 
    person.sa = "S123";
```